# Deepcrawl getting data : Undefined Offset 1

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api

Deepcrawl.php

```
<?php 

$array_issues[] = 0;

$issues = array("thin_pages_basic","not_in_sitemaps_primary_indexable_basic","duplicate_titles_2_basic","pages_with_duplicate_titles_basic","max_external_links_basic","4xx_errors_basic");

for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"Your Api key". $issues[$i]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Auth-Token:91PB_EP-LSaTVcm2bCjWyE9oLBEhGYSpvuW-gILR1eCEiK-VPL4YO40L8hTFTnepC8HjaLgn2C3AG6k3iv_-zg'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output2 = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 

$results = json_decode($server_output2);

$j=0;
// to get each object from an array of object
foreach((array)$results as $result){ 
  if($j==3)
  $array_issues[$i] = $result;

  $j++;
  }
} 
?>
```

Displaying in the view file

```
                 <tr>
                    <td style='color:#e86363'>" . $array_issues[0] . "</td>
                    <td style='width:50px'></td>
                    <td>Thin Pages</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style='color:#e86363'>" . $array_issues[1] . "</td>
                    <td style='width:50px'></td>
                    <td>Primary Indexable Pages Not in Sitemaps </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style='color:#e86363'>" . $array_issues[2] . "</td>
                    <td style='width:50px'></td>
                    <td>Duplicate Title Sets</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style='color:#e86363'>" . $array_issues[3] . "</td>
                    <td style='width:50px'></td>
                    <td>Pages with Duplicate Titles</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style='color:#e86363'>" . $array_issues[4] . "</td>
                    <td style='width:50px'></td>
                    <td>High External Linking</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style='color:#e86363'>" . $array_issues[5] . "</td>
                    <td style='width:50px'></td>
                    <td>Broken Pages (4xx Errors)</td>
                </tr>
```

Just wondering when I'm declaring on my view file I always got this error `Undefined offset: 1`

But when I change the array from [1-5] to [0] it works okay but it didn't get any data at all? If you see whats causing this, posting below would really help. Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($array_issues);`?

Comment: It seems you meant to replace your auth token with an abstraction, but you've actually replaced your URL and left your token in place. You probably want to change/revoke that token immediately.

Comment: Print your array and check array having actually offsets that you are accessing

Comment: @AlexHowansky I just need to hide my api key. that's why I leave my auth token out there. But thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: array(6) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" } @aynber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change your `$array_issues` declaration to either

```php
$array_issues = array();
```

or

```php
$array_issues = [];
```

Then, i don't know what you are trying to accomplish in this lines:

```php
$results = json_decode($server_output2);

$j=0;
// to get each object from an array of object
foreach((array)$results as $result){ 
    if($j==3)
    $array_issues[$i] = $result;

    $j++;
}
```

But, i don't think this is initializing your `$array_issues[0]` index correctly, it may not even be entering this... i would at least initialize the index outside that if and foreach, something like:

```php
$j=0;
// to get each object from an array of object
$array_issues[$i] = ""; // MAKING SURE THIS IS AT LEAST DEFINED.
foreach((array)$results as $result){ 
    if($j==3)
    $array_issues[$i] = $result;

    $j++;
}
```

Also, i think you could accomplish what you are trying to do with a $key => $value syntax instead of that $j counter...

```
$array_issues[$i] = ""; // MAKING SURE THIS IS AT LEAST DEFINED.
foreach((array)$results as $key => $result){ 
    if($key==3)
    $array_issues[$i] = $result;
}
```

Comment: you have any example how to do that?

Comment: $key => $value syntax? ... supposing the array keys are numeric, i added it to the answer

Comment: tried that already. but when i var_dump($array_issues); All of them is zero

Comment: Where are you dumping it ? After all this runs ? In the view ?

Comment: at the controller.

Comment: I think its because of my X-Auth-Token is not updated that's why.

Comment: The session token remains valid for 6 hours, then must be regenerated. Source : http://api-docs.deepcrawl.com/

Comment: Was it really that ? i don't think that matters, 6 hours should be long enough.